# Installing Plesk on Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: software-installation

Can someone tell me how i can install Plesk Panel on Ubuntu 11.04?

I can't find an version on the Customer Page and the Setup tells me:

```
Installation will not continue because your operating system
"'Ubuntu' 'Linux' '11.04' 'x86_64' under vz" is not supported.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plesk Panel only supports Ubuntu "LTS" releases. In Plesk Panel v11, it supports 10.04 and 12.04.